# Delete combo box linked to a cell

Tags: excel, vba

Recently I encountered a problem that I linked a combo box to a specific cell but i want everytime the data in the sheet change, the combo box will be create again and the old combo box will be deleted. So here is my code. The problem is everytime target change new combo box will show up, so if the target is the one i have changed before, there will be 2 combo boxes lie on each others. How can I remove the previous combo box?
Thanks for your responses.

```
Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("J" & Target.Row)
     Range("J" & Target.Row).Clear
    Set Ob2 = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=10.5, Top:=10, Width:=10, Height:=10)
    Ob2.Object.List = shArray()
    Ob1.LinkedCell = "J" & Target.Row
    With rng
        Ob2.Left = rng2.Left
        Ob2.Top = rng2.Top
        Ob2.Width = rng2.Width
        Ob2.Height = rng2.Height
    End With
```

Comment: I don't have any solution to this. Can you share the solution with me? I would be very thankful

Comment: I have post the code, sorry if my expression so bad

Comment: Can you confirm - is this inside a `Worksheet_Change` event?

Comment: Yes it is inside change event

Comment: I would think the approach would be to loop through the comboboxes on the sheet and see if any have a `LinkedCell` equal to `"J" & Target.Row`... if so, delete. Untested

Answer (score 0):

You can make the dynamic name range and add to the combo . it should not be delete and add every time.